# How to write one method in base class if method uses different types depending on the derived class?

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, types, enums

The question sounds more complicated than it actually is. I have a simplified example below. Pink highlights indicate the differences between two classes. As you can see, the only real difference is in the enum type that is used. All other code is identical. Is there any way to use inheritance and/or templation to have only one GetTrialType() method in my entire codebase? I am showing two derived classes in this example (NBACK and COLOR), but in actuality there are hundreds of classes derived from the Task class. This means if I have to make one change to the GetTrialType() method, I will actually have to make 100 updates. How can I prevent this (when different types are used)?

[image: Diff]

Comment: How does your code work? How does `trialTypes(trial)` know what type to return?

Comment: why are you giving diff names to enum when the options are same for both?

Comment: @Zache: Would love to hear more about your solution. Does a base class allow you to create member variables with templated types? Does it allow you to create methods which are not implemented in the base class but only in the derived class?

Comment: @nvoigt: trialTypes[trial] is just a Dictionary, which is a private member variable of the derived class.

Comment: @Patel: Sometimes they have different options. Sometimes they have the same options but the values are different.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use int instead of the enumeration in that dictionary. In the derived classes every time you add any type into the `trialTypes` you would have to cast it to int, whereas every time you get a type by calling `GetTrialType` you would have to cast it back to the enumeration type. In your Task class you could have:

```
    private Dictionary<int, int> trialTypes;

    protected int GetTrialType(int trial)
    {
        try
        {
            return trialTypes[trial];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // your logging ...
        }

        return 0;
    }

    protected void AddTrialType(int trial, int type)
    {
        trialTypes.Add(trial, type);
    }
```